# Adding a class/changing css property of navbar upon scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar's background colour is transparent in the header. But when I scroll down and the navbar hits the next section, I want its background colour to turn black. The code I've tried isn't working. Please have a look and see where I'm wrong? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="header" id="header">
     <div class="container">

         <div class="img"><img src="img.jpg">      
         <button><a role="button" href="#about">&darr;</a></button>

     </div>
 </div>




<div class="about" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center top">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
}

.nav-bg-black {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#about").waypoint(function(direction){
       if(direction == "down"){
           $(".navbar-default").css("background-color", "#000");
       } else {
           $(".navbar-default").css("background-color", "transparent");
       }
    }, {
            offset: '60px'
    });
```

And

```
$("#about").waypoint(function(direction){
       if(direction == "down"){
           $(".navbar-default").addClass("nav-bg-black");
       } else {
           $(".navbar-default").removeClass("nav-bg-black");
       }
    }, {
            offset: '60px'
    });
```

Comment: .navbar-default doesn't appear in your markup. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Can you put it in a jsfiddle or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap you can use class .navbar-inverse

Here is the sample i've tried and it is working
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/ye7z26Lx/4/

Code Changes:

```
 $(function(){    
    $("#about").waypoint(function(direction){
       if(direction == "down"){
           $(".navbar-default").addClass("navbar-inverse");
       } else {
           $(".navbar-default").removeClass("navbar-inverse");
       }
    }, {
            offset: '60px'
    });

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: $("#about"),
    handler: function (direction) {
        if (direction == "down") {
            $(".navbar-default").css("background-color", "#000");
        } else {
            $(".navbar-default").css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    },
    offset: '60px'
});
```